VSCode not recognizing user.name and user.email in git for BitBucket Repo
I am having issues pushing to a repo on bitbucket from vscode
I have a repo cloned from bitbucket on vscode, and am attempting to commit and push a test text document. i already wrote git config user.name and email --global , then tested to see if it saved by sending git config user.name and it returns the username i input, but the commiting is still not working bcs it says I have to configure name and email still

Looks like you didn't do a git config --global user.email "you@emaildomain".   You can use git config -l to see how git is configured.

I did, I just forgot to mention that. when i do the git config -l , it shows that my username and email are what i've input

What OS is your workstation?  Did you try from the cli rather than from the vscode terminal?  Is your code on a remote server?  There are any number of things this could be.  git commit is a local command.  Are you running this from the directory where the project was cloned?  You have to be in that directory to run git commands?  Are you trying to use vscode's git support?  What is the EXACT error message you received when running git commit.

I'm on windows. I don't have the cli. I'm pretty sure I'm running from the exact directory. The error says, "Make sure you configure your "user.name" and "user.email" in git"

There is something you are missing and the way to verify things is to use the cli/aka the terminal.  When you ran git config -l where did you do that?  There are different ways to set git up on windows.  If you used https://gitforwindows.org/ then you will have gitbash installed.  Gitbash is a cli (the bash shell) preconfigured for git use.  You can also set vscode to use gitbash as the terminal.  Are you using a docker container?
